# Using Auto scoll within ListView showing blank rows in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm building a Smart Mirror App.
The bottom section of the screen contains a ListView, that is populated with NASA News from a custom Adapter.
This list view shows 3 articles on screen, there are 10 articles. If i scroll using touch it shows the rest of the rows.
Using the following code in my program to auto scroll, scrolls the 3 visible articles OK, but when it scrolls up form off screen the following articles are blank.

```js
        final long totalScrollTime = Long.MAX_VALUE; //total scroll time. I think that 300 000 000 years is close enouth to infinity. if not enought you can restart timer in onFinish()
        final int scrollPeriod = 9000; // every 20 ms scoll will happened. smaller values for smoother
        final int heightToScroll = 140; // will be scrolled to 20 px every time. smaller values for smoother scrolling

        storiesListViewObj.post(new Runnable()
        {
        @Override
            public void run()
        {
                new CountDownTimer(totalScrollTime, scrollPeriod )
                {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                    {
                        storiesListViewObj.scrollBy(0, heightToScroll);
                    }
                    public void onFinish()
                    {
                        //you can add code for restarting timer here
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

i've been messing about for days and cannot solve the problem. Could anyone please help.

Comment: I've solved the problem by changing storiesListViewObj.scrollBy(0, heightToScroll); to storiesListViewObj.scrollListBy(heightToScroll);

Answer (score 0):

I have soloved this way :

```
final long totalScrollTime = Long.MAX_VALUE; //total scroll time. I think that 300 000 000 years is close enouth to infinity. if not enought you can restart timer in onFinish()
        final int scrollPeriod = 9000; // every 20 ms scoll will happened. smaller values for smoother
        final int heightToScroll = 140; // will be scrolled to 20 px every time. smaller values for smoother scrolling

        storiesListViewObj.post(new Runnable()
        {
        @Override
            public void run()
        {
                new CountDownTimer(totalScrollTime, scrollPeriod )
                {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                    {
                        storiesListViewObj.scrollListBy(heightToScroll);
                    }
                    public void onFinish()
                    {
                        //you can add code for restarting timer here
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```